# R maps package - how to draw lines between cities within the country?

Tags: r

I have an Esri shape file(a multipolygon), with all city of my county in my own country coordinate system (`srid:23700`). I would like to draw lines between cities? How can I do it in R?

I tried to copy this pattern, I changed the country names to city names:

```
library(maptools)
library(geosphere)

data(wrld_simpl)

US_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']
US_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']

SWE_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']
SWE_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']

points = gcIntermediate(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(SWE_lon, SWE_lat), 100)

dev.new(width=6, height=4)
plot(wrld_simpl)
lines(points, col='red')
```

but that does not work

I got this error:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : 
  points should be vectors of length 2, matrices with 2 columns, or inheriting from a SpatialPoints* object
```

I imported the data this way:

```
cities <-readShapePoly("cities.shp")
```

I tried this one(not working), How can I specify my own projection???:

```
readShapeSpatial("cities.shp", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat"))
```

So I would like to make lines between cities.

Thanks

Comment: you want to draw lines for all pairs of cities?

Comment: no, I want to draw lines from all cities to one specific city
I would like to make same thing just within a country: [image](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/163413_479288597199_8388607_n.jpg)

Comment: your code is working just fine for me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working just fine for me.

```
kpacks <- c("ggmap", 'sp','rgdal', 'maptools', 'geosphere')
new.packs <- kpacks[!(kpacks %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packs)) install.packages(new.packs)
lapply(kpacks, require, character.only=T)
remove(kpacks, new.packs)
```

load data

```
data(wrld_simpl)

US_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']
US_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']

SWE_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']
SWE_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Sweden']
```

Great circle points

```
points = gcIntermediate(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(SWE_lon, SWE_lat), n=10,
                        addStartEnd=T)
```

Plot it

```
plot(wrld_simpl, col = 'grey', border = NA, axes = T)
lines(points, col='red')
text(x=0, y=65, "Hello!", pos = 1)
```

[image: general plot]

or

```
bbox <- ggmap::make_bbox(lon, lat, points, f = 1.1)
> bbox
       left      bottom       right         top 
-223.869600    7.676652  140.533600  100.608574
```

I don't like it as returned by ggmap.

```
bbox <- c('left' = -110, 'bottom' = 20, 'right' = 30, 'top' = 80)

map_loc <- get_map(location = bbox, source = 'google', maptype = 'roadmap')
map <- ggmap(map_loc, extent = 'panel', maprange=FALSE, darken = c(0.5, "white"))
map + geom_path(aes(x=lon, y=lat), data = data.frame(points))
```

[image: ggmap]

For your dataset you could try someting like this:

Read country data

```
hun <- readOGR(dsn='D:/Temporarios/r_project', layer = 'telepulesek')
```

Is it projected? If so, get it as unprojected layer

```
if(is.projected(hun)) hun <- spTransform(hun, CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
```

Get centroids of each administrative division and attribute data.

```
ctd <- data.frame(nev = hun@data$Nev, azon = hun@data$Azon, coordinates(hun))
head(ctd)
```

Attribute data with unrecognized Hungarian characters

```
> head(ctd)
             nev azon       X1       X2
0        FÃœZÃ‰R 1710 26.90856 44.25363
1   HIDVÃ‰GARDÃ“ 2567 26.33393 44.28779
2 FÃœZÃ‰RKOMLÃ“S 1137 26.87719 44.23257
3         KÃ‰KED 1526 26.82228 44.25519
4    HOLLÃ“HÃZA  3116 26.87083 44.24943
5     PUSZTAFALU 1704 26.94799 44.24740
```

Get Great circle lines as spatialLines (`sp = T`) object. I'm using 1st adm division as my 'from' and a few random as 'to'. You can change it as required using 'Nev' or 'Azon' attributes.

For specific Azon codes

```
azonp1 <- 3336 # from
azonp2 <- 1513 # to
lines_hun = gcIntermediate(subset(ctd, azon %in% azonp1, select = c('X1', 'X2')),
                           subset(ctd, azon %in% azonp2, select = c('X1', 'X2')),
                           n = 10, addStartEnd=T, sp = T)
par(bg='white', cex = 0.6)
plot(hun, col = '#000040', border = '#19198c', axes = T)
plot(lines_hun, col = 'white', add = T)
```

[image: plot azon]

You can add codes to azonp2 simply building a vector with codes c(1513, 1514, ...)

If you don't want a spatial object as result of `gcIntermediate` set `sp = F` and run something like

```
flines <- function(x){
  x <- data.frame(x)
  lines(x$lon, x$lat, col = 'white')
}

plot(hun, col = '#000040', border = '#19198c', axes = T)
mapply(flines, lines_hun)



> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Portugal.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Portugal.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Portugal.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mapproj_1.2-2   maps_2.3-6      geosphere_1.3-8 rgdal_0.8-16    ggmap_2.3       ggplot2_0.9.3.1
[7] maptools_0.8-29 sp_1.0-14      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4    dichromat_2.0-0     digest_0.6.4        foreign_0.8-59      grid_3.0.2         
 [6] gtable_0.1.2        labeling_0.2        lattice_0.20-27     MASS_7.3-29         munsell_0.4.2      
[11] plyr_1.8.1          png_0.1-7           proto_0.3-10        RColorBrewer_1.0-5  Rcpp_0.11.0        
[16] reshape2_1.2.2      RgoogleMaps_1.2.0.5 rjson_0.2.13        RJSONIO_1.0-3       scales_0.2.3       
[21] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.0.2        
>
```

Comment: At first thank you, but I'd like to use my own input data, a multipolygon. Is it possible?

Comment: @Balazs, Could you provide a sample data for training?

Comment: I really really appriciate your help @Paulo Cardoso :))

Comment: `lines_hun = gcIntermediate(ctd[1,c('X1', 'X2')],
                           ctd[c(100,200,500,2000),
                               c('X1', 'X2')],
                           n=10, addStartEnd=FALSE, sp = T)`

number 1 after ctd is azon or the row serial number? and c(100,200,500,2000) means row serial numbers or azon's?

Comment: Id like to start from Azon=3336 to Azon=1513

Comment: @Balazs What is the Azon code to use as 'from' in the map? You want the entire range from 1513:3336 as 'to'?

Comment: I would like to draw a line from Azon 3336 (attribute number) to 1513
(these two means two city)