# ggmap with coordinates with curved arrows between cities in R

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, coordinates, ggmap

I would like to make a map of the Netherlands with curved lines between cities. I have two dataframes number one called: `df_verticles` which contains 24 cities with their lat/lon combination. The second dataframe called: `df` i want to use to draw a curved line between lat/lon from combination to the lat/lon to combination.

```
> head(df_vertices)
        city AmountSessions   totalkWh AmountRFID scaledAmount   scaledkWh Latitude Longitude
1    Alkmaar          13608  104554.68       1326   0.07139012 0.026941910 52.63903  4.755538
2     Almere          11281  100841.42        930   0.05006999 0.025985067 52.39447  5.282043
3 Amersfoort           7719   67663.30       1198   0.06449876 0.017435647 52.15108  5.383069
4 Amstelveen          25794  236437.93       2616   0.14084204 0.060925915 52.31724  4.859266
5  Amsterdam         402365 3880744.86      18574   1.00000000 1.000000000 52.34560  4.808834


> head(df)
  CityChargeSessions   NextCity Amount    sumkWh scaledAmount  scaledkWh Latitude_from Longitude_from Latitude_to Longitude_to
1          Amsterdam    Alkmaar   1058  8133.736   0.18438480 0.15480933      52.34560       4.808834    52.63903     4.755538
2          Amsterdam     Almere    998  7254.133   0.17392820 0.13806786      52.34560       4.808834    52.39447     5.282043
3          Amsterdam Amersfoort    566  4977.404   0.09864064 0.09473489      52.34560       4.808834    52.15108     5.383069
4          Amsterdam Amstelveen   3724 24210.289   0.64900662 0.46079423      52.34560       4.808834    52.31724     4.859266
5             Almere  Amsterdam   1034  8685.526   0.18020216 0.16531155      52.39447       5.282043    52.34560     4.808834
6         Amersfoort  Amsterdam    579  4936.823   0.10090624 0.09396251      52.15108       5.383069    52.34560     4.808834

map <- get_map(location = "Schiphol", zoom = 9, source = "google")
p1 <- ggmap(map)+
   geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, size=scaledkWh), data = df_vertices, alpha =0.5)+
   scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,30)) + 
   geom_segment(data=df, aes(x=Longitude_from, y=Latitude_from, xend=Longitude_to, yend=Latitude_to),
           arrow=arrow(ends="first"), size= df$scaledAmount,alpha=0.75)
```

This is my output so far:

[image]

As you can see in this image above, some lines overlap which is not nice. Could anyone help me how to code this to curved lines between the cities.

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you seen this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282713/r-maps-package-how-to-draw-lines-between-cities-within-the-country

Comment: Thank you! unfortonetly geom_path does'nt work with arrows from/to combinations.In my example not every city have an arrow to another city, for example "Alkmaar" has an arrow from "Amsterdam".

Comment: @M.Kooi Probably pretty late, but perhaps here's something you may find useful. It's for Leaflet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419804/ggmap-with-coordinates-with-curved-arrows-between-cities-in-r